# while loop isn't working

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have a quick question. I have the following code...

```
def abc(c):
    a = 1
    my = set()
    while a <= c:
        b = randrange(1, 365)
        my.add(b)
        a = a + 1
    print(my)
```

Now c is in my main function. c is a integer that the user is prompted for. For instance, if c = 10, then as long as a < 10 it will run the while loop and print out the set with 10 numbers randomly generated between 1 and 365. The only problem is that it's not printing out the set my correctly.

Comment: `randint()` *includes* the endpoint, so you get random values between 1 and 366. Use `randrange()` if you expect the end point not to be included.

Comment: Your local names do not match. `my` is not the same as `mySet`.

Comment: The answer was solved. I have to wait 12 minutes to accept it. Thanks guys

Comment: @MartijnPieters do you think you could help me with the 2nd problem?

Comment: You should not add new problems to an existing, answered question; I see you now added a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578747/comparing-values-in-a-set); that's the right thing to do.

Comment: Sorry, I was going to edit this problem again to remove the second question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a = a+1 should be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`a + 1` just increments the value of a, but does not store it anywhere. So, using `a = a+1`, will increment the value of a and update the value of a.

The second part: You are generating the random numbers and storing them in a set, and printing them at last. To print each and every element in the list, use:

```
for i in my:
    print i
```

This will print each value in the set

Comment: Hey, do you know how I could solve the second part to my problem @Aswin Murugesh