# comparing values in a set

Tags: python, set

so my code currently generates a set with random integers between 1 and 200. It does this by using a while loop to add values to the set. What I'm having trouble doing is comparing values in a set to see if 2 values are duplicated. If they are, I want to return a bool value or an actual print statement saying they are duplicates. Similarly, I would want to stop generating a set if the duplicate is found within this

```
def abc(c):
    a = 1
    my = set()
    while a <= c:
        b = randrange(1, 200)
        my.add(b)
        a = a + 1
    print(my)
```

Comment: You are adding random integers between 1 and 366, not 200.

Comment: It's a set - there are no duplicate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test for membership with `in`:

```
while a <= c:
    b = randrange(1, 200)
    if b in my:
        print('Duplicate random value generated')
    my.add(b)
    a = a + 1
```

Note that you could use a `for` loop with a `range()` call instead of a `while` loop here, to loop `c` times:

```
for i in range(c):
    b = randrange(1, 200)
    if b in my:
        print('Duplicate random value generated')
    my.add(b)
```

Comment: I get the error set object not callable. Also if I add a break after the print statement would it stop the while loop? Nevermind, found the solution to my problem. I have to wait to approve this answer.

Comment: @user2908101: a `break` would stop the loop, yes. What code raises the `set object not callable` error? The only names that are being called in my code are `print()` and `randrange()`, plus `range()` in my second example. Did you accidentally rebind one of those names in your code?

Comment: the problem was calling my() which brings about that error too